# Is the bitmap recycling process asynchronous?

Tags: android

I have method that returns `Drawable`, and if its `Bitmap` object is recycled then it reloads.

```
public Drawable getLogo() {
    if(logo == null || Util.isRecycled(logo)) //Util.isRecycled checks - is Drawable's bitmap recycled, if it had so
        logo = CacheController.getInstance().getLogo(this);

    return logo;
}
```

But looks like right after calling `bitmap.recycle()` it's `bitmap.isRecycled()` still returns `false`. Am I right, that bitmap recycle process goes asynchonously, or it's just bug in my code? If so, how can I make sure, that `Bitmap` is not recycled right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement some caching mechanism for bitmaps, you shouldn't have to check if it's recycled. Simply retrieve it from the cache and the cache will create it again if it doesn't have a reference to it in it's data structure. See this tutorial for how to cache bitmaps http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html